# Wood puzzle of 6 equal parts

Tags: puzzle-identification

I got a wooden puzzle (I guess it is a puzzle) consisting of six equal and symmetric parts (four of them from different angles in the picture).

[image: Wooden puzzle]

I have no manual and would like to know what its name is and how it should look like when assembled together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a 3-d star puzzle like the one [here](https://www.solve-it-puzzles.com/products/star-puzzle)?

Answer (score 2):

I happen to have a very small plastic version of this puzzle. It contains 6 trapezoidal pieces

- 1 **plain** bar
- 3 **notched** bars
- 2 **wicked** bars

Here is the construction sequence

> The outer edge of each piece is the longest straight edge without any notching (A).
>
>  Start by holding the **wicked** pair, with their extra notch away from you (B and C).
>  Insert a **notched** bar with its notches uppermost. Don't push it all the way in.
>  Insert another **notched** bar with its notches downmost. Align it with the first one (D).
>  Take the third **notched** bar and slide it between the other two, notches innermost (E).
>  Now push that set of three **notched** bars in as far as possible (F and G).
>  Finally slide in the **plain** bar. There are two ways – match up the ends to align (H and I).
>
>  [image]
>
>  Despite the *appearance* of being interlocking, it is only held together by friction, as can be seen when you try to separate the pieces all at once (J).